# Reading a simple diagram, how to practically implement this on a breadboard

Tags: resistors, voltage-regulator, diagram

So yes, I'm brand new to circuitry, and I'm looking to implement a very simple diagram in order to boost a 3.3v output to 12v output.

I've picked up a [lm317T](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LM317) from the local electronics shop and I'm currently supplying my breadboard with 3.3v.

What does the practical application of this look like?

[image: LM317T Diagram]

I realize this is super simple for most of you, but I'm not totally up on how it works.

- Is R2 (resistor 2) connected to the ground?
- How do I figure out which resistors I need?
- How do I calculate the formula to take a 3.3V input and dump out a 12V output?

$$V_{out} = (1 + \frac{R2}{R1}) +  ADJ_{R2}$$

*note: R2 is not adjustable in my scenario, but rather it's going to be a fixed resistor in order to give a consistant output*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conventional voltage regulators like the LM317 don't do what you're trying to do.  They regulate a higher voltage down to a particular (lower) voltage.  If you're trying to boost a DC voltage to a higher level you can convert it to AC, run it through a transformer and then rectify it back to DC, or you could use a DC to DC converter known as a "boost converter" or "step up converter" (or "step up regulator"). See:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter

Here's one example of such a part:

http://www.newark.com/linear-technology/lt3581emse-pbf/ic-boost-inverting-dc-dc-conv-msop/dp/71R4698

Edit:

Also, depending on exactly what you're trying to accomplish, there might be other approaches.  For example, if you aren't necessarily trying to convert one voltage TO another voltage, but rather to *control* a signal at one voltage using a signal at a different voltage, you may only need a transistor, or perhaps an opto-isolator.

Comment: oh interesting. What supplies would I need to build my own step up converter? Or is that going to be way too much for what I'm looking to do?

Comment: **Post Edit:** End of the day, I'm taking 3.3v out of my Netduino, boosting it to 12v and powering an LED Strip.

Comment: Ah, ok, kinda thought it might be something like that.  Probably the most straight-forward way to do that is to have an independent power supply (supplying the correct voltage and amperage for the load), switched by a MOSFET transistor.  Use the output from the Netduino pin to control the gate of the MOSFET.  Trying to drive a significant load directly off of an output pin from a microcontroller isn't really a good idea... the microcontroller can't usually source that much current and you'll damage it if you draw too much current.  Look for a "logic level" MOSFET like an IRL540N or similar.

Comment: something along [these lines](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/1-x-IRF540N-IRF540-IR-MOSFET-N-Channel-33A-100V-/140601878899?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item20bc866973)?

Comment: Close, but that may not be exactly what you want. You'll have to study the data-sheet to be sure you've found what you need. There are two important things you need to look for: The total current through the drain to source, that the MOSFET can carry, and the Vgs(threshold) value. Vgs is the voltage between the gate and the source, and it controls when the MOSFET "turns on." You want one that turn at a "logic level" voltage. Note that MOSFETs are linear devices, so they turn "more on" as the Vgs value rises. You want one that will be pretty much fully on at a "logic level" voltage (3.3-5.0)

Comment: Looking at this one, it appears to only fully turn on at around 7V, which is a bit high. You can use a MOSFET in the "linear mode" range where it isn't quite fully on, but the resistance will be higher than expected and it may overheat at less than it's rated load. To really tell you have to dig into the data sheet and find the graph that shows the relationship between Vgs and the drain-source current. If the "knee of the curve" happens before the voltage you'll be sending, you're set. Note that "logic level" MOSFETs will usually have an "L" in the part number (example, IRL540N).

Comment: If you look at this data sheet, and look down to figure 3, note that the "knee of the curve" is at around 3 volts.  That's more like what you want.  You can drive that from the output of a microcontroller (although note that you might need a resistor in the gate circuit, so you don't draw too much current from the output pin).  http://www.futurlec.com/Transistors/IRL540N.shtml  An opto-isolator isn't strictly required for doing this, but it might still be a good idea to protect your microcontroller. If you poke around the forums at arduino.cc, there's a ton of info on doing this sort of thing.

Comment: Wow, a lot to take in. I sorta wish there were DIY kits to get started...

Comment: Dropped into the local Radio Shack hoping I could see some results on this project today... looks like it's not gonna happen. I honestly didn't think it'd be this hard.

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know, Radio Shack does not carry a proper logic-level MOSFET, just the IRF510.  This trips a lot of people us (myself included) when they first start trying to control external loads from a microcontroller.  The logic level parts are readily available online though.  I think those IRL540's I mentioned above are about a buck each from Jameco.  I'd just order about 10 of them and then you'll be set for a while.

Comment: But like you said, there are various ones and I don't know exactly what I need. Simply put... 12V DC into breadboard... 3.3v Output IO... need to power 12V DC LED Strip.

Comment: Yep, there are a lot of parts available, but you don't necessarily have to sort through all of them to make a decision.  After you do this a while, you'll A. memorize certain common, broadly applicable parts, and / or B. learn to use the "parametric search" feature on the various vendor websites.  For now, do you know how many amps (total) your LED strip draws? If it's less than 36 (which seems very likely), that IRL540N should work. It's rated for 36A at 25 degrees celsius, with a GS voltage of 10V (but it can take a gs voltage of 16 volts, and can go up to 100V on the drain-source path).

Comment: Don't know the amperage. It's all in [Chinese](http://minkara.carview.co.jp/userid/626972/car/534565/2779580/parts.aspx).  I'm assuming you're correct however.